# Why is cosine in the equation?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, coulombs-law

I do not understand why there is a cosine in the expression. I found the answer by taking the vector sum first and multiplying everything afterwards, resulting in the same answer, but I don’t understand the solution shown in the picture

[image]

P.S:If anyone knows an explained exercise like this one, please give me a link or name of literature.

Comment: The example assumes the knowledge about how to sum two vectors. I suggest you do some practice with it before going to electrostatics.

Answer (score 1):

The description explains why actually. You aren't looking for the electric field in the horizontal direction, because they necessarily cancel. You are only looking for the electric field in the vertical direction.

What is that electric field? If you draw the triangle, you'll see you need a cosine to get the vertical component.

Comment: I should explain, I understand why the horizontal components of vectors cancel each other, but I can't understand where we got the cosine from. After all, the information about the direction of the vector is stored in its unit vector, are we getting the cosine from it?

Comment: The cosine is the vertical component. Do you know how to add vectors? If not I would revising that carefully.